# How to view the data that went through a Classifier?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, classification

I have a Bernoulli classifier which I run on a random set of classified data. The model performs relatively well (~92%), but I was wondering if there was a way to see the data after it has gone through the classifier (i.e. see which data point got classified as what by the classifier). This is my current code:

```
docs_train_n, docs_test_n, y_train_n, y_test_n = train_test_split(x_dt.sent_lemmas, x_dt.iloc[:, 1], test_size = 0.33, random_state = 12)

dtm_train_n=cv_tdif.fit_transform(docs_train_n)
dtm_test_n=cv_tdif.transform(docs_test_n)


clf_n = BernoulliNB()
clf_n.fit(dtm_train_n, y_train_n)
y_pred_n = clf_n.predict(dtm_test_n)
cm_n= confusion_matrix(y_test_n, y_pred_n)

print(cm_n)


#ROC-AOC curves


y_pred_prob_n = clf_n.predict_proba(dtm_test_n)[:,1]
fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y_test_n, y_pred_prob_n)

plt.subplots(1, figsize=(10,10))
plt.title('Receiver Operating Characteristic - TD-IF Vectorizer: BernoulliNB')
plt.plot(fpr, tpr)
plt.plot([0, 1], ls="--")
plt.plot([0, 0], [1, 0] , c=".7"), plt.plot([1, 1] , c=".7")
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.show()

auc = roc_auc_score(y_true=y_test_n, y_score=y_pred_prob_n)
print('Area under curve is {}'.format(round(auc, 2)))
```

Comment: Did my answer help? If not please elaborate. If yes, maybe consider accepting?

Answer (score 1):

There are two "modes" of output from your classifier; using `.predict` returns discrete class labels, while `.predict_proba` returns a vector of probabilities of belonging to each class. So for a two class scenario, this output is not binary, so the request to see

> which data point got classified as what by the classifier

would be ill defined.
(Again, what you get is a continuum of scores which can be interpreted as probabilities of being from one class or the other).
You can view this in multiple formats, such as a scatter plot of scores colored by the true class label (`plt.scatter`), distributions of scores by class (`seaborn`'s `sns.distplot`), etc.
Alternatively, you can view a binarized classification output by thresholding the outputs and then showing examples of true/false-positive/negative cases.
Different thresholds would give different results, which is exactly what your ROC is displaying; performance as the thresholding varies.

---

More generally, I highly recommend understanding *what* your code actually *does*. Just coding away without knowing what the meaning of the different functions being used isn't the way to go about things...
Here's an annotated version of your code that should help get you on track:

```
# Split your dataset into two distinct subsets, with a train:test ratio of ~2:1. 
# Out put is train-inputs, test-inputs, train-labels, test-labels, in that order.
docs_train_n, docs_test_n, y_train_n, y_test_n = train_test_split(x_dt.sent_lemmas, x_dt.iloc[:, 1], test_size = 0.33, random_state = 12)

# No code describing cv_tdif, but I'm guessing that this is an embedding transformation. The output is the training input data in the feature space relevant for fitting your naive-bayes-bernoulli-model. 
dtm_train_n=cv_tdif.fit_transform(docs_train_n)
dtm_test_n=cv_tdif.transform(docs_test_n)

# Create bernoulli-naive-bayes classifier instance
clf_n = BernoulliNB()

# Fit the model with the training data (inputs and labels)
clf_n.fit(dtm_train_n, y_train_n)

# Use trained model to predict labels on the test input-data
# Outputs binary predictions, thresholded with 0.5 
# (and more generally, for multi-class, just by using the maximal probability)
y_pred_n = clf_n.predict(dtm_test_n)

# Produce a confusion matrix comparing true labels and estimated labels
cm_n= confusion_matrix(y_test_n, y_pred_n)

# Print said confusion-matrix
print(cm_n)


#ROC-AOC curves

# Get probability predictions, and instead of looking at the probability for each class, 
# only return the probabilities of the second class
y_pred_prob_n = clf_n.predict_proba(dtm_test_n)[:,1]

# Produce false-positive-rate and true-positive-rate as function of threshold-varying, 
# along with the thresholds that produce these specific FPR and TPR. 
# TPR as function of FPR is exactly a ROC-curve
fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y_test_n, y_pred_prob_n)

# Plot ROC curve (with title, defining lines for qualitative comparison, labels, etc.)
plt.subplots(1, figsize=(10,10))
plt.title('Receiver Operating Characteristic - TD-IF Vectorizer: BernoulliNB')
plt.plot(fpr, tpr)
plt.plot([0, 1], ls="--")
plt.plot([0, 0], [1, 0] , c=".7"), plt.plot([1, 1] , c=".7")
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.show()

# Calculate (and print) the area under the ROC curve. 
# This is an aggregational scalar describing the quality of your classifier. 
# ROC-AUC = 1 is a perfect classifier, ROC-AUC=0.5 is as good as random. 
auc = roc_auc_score(y_true=y_test_n, y_score=y_pred_prob_n)
print('Area under curve is {}'.format(round(auc, 2)))
```

---

Order of estimated labels is the same as inputs. So each input has a specific and precise corresponding output.
This allows for indexed examination of specific test-samples:

```
ind = 17
test_document = docs_test_n[ind]
test_embedded_vector = dtm_test_n[ind]
prob_of_beloning_to_class_2 = y_pred_prob_n[ind]
```

As well as the plots I recommended.

Comment: Do you know where these numbers are stored in the object?

Comment: Going by your code, I'm assuming that's exactly what `y_pred_prob_n` is